# Creating an Android application that fetches data from self hosted WCF Service

Tags: java, c#, android, web-services, wcf

This is the first time I am implementing WCF web-services. I have already created a WCF web-service which fetches data from XML document and return the data when the function is called. This WCF web service is self-hosted.

I want to create an Android application (using SOAP) such that on pressing a button, it should call that particular function in web service and fetches the data and then displaying in the textview in android.

I do not know how to call the local host in Android.

Comment: Here's a [community discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/472495) about urgent begging.

Answer (score 0):

```
You cannot connect the WCF Service on localhost in Android.

For Android to be able to consume the WCF Service , the Android device and WCF service should be in same network.

Once your Android device and WCF service are on same network, You can consume the WCF Service by using the IP Address of system on which WCF Service is hosted.
```